# Can we add custom validation to Editor Part Property?

Tags: asp.net, xss, web-parts, customvalidator, editor-zone

I have Appearance Editor Part in my application. I have an requirement like i have to include a custom validation like required field validation to the Title Property of Appearance Editor Part. How to include this?

I found many answers to change to custom web part rather than Appearance Editor Part. But in my project , i cannot do this. I want to include custom validator to the title property of Appearance Editor part alone.

Comment: What's this got to do with `XSS`?

Comment: The custom validation I am going to add is regards to Cross Site Scripting. I am going to Add Anti xss validator.